# Python3 dictionary compare, nested dictionaries with numpy arrays

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, dictionary, compare

I want to compare dictionaries in python. I know that I can simply do `a == b`, if `a` and `b` are dictionaries. This also works for nested dictionaries, where a and b contain dictionaries themselves. However, it does not work if a and b contain numpy arrays of size>1:

```
import numpy as np
a = {"1": np.array([1, 2])}
b = {"1": np.array([1, 2])}
a == b
```

I get this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "", line 1, in 
>   ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

I did check: [this post](https:///stackoverflow.com/questions/4527942/comparing-two-dictionaries-and-checking-how-many-key-value-pairs-are-equal) and found the suggestion of `import deepdiff` from  [sumbudu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1547699/sumudu) which does what I want. However, is there an easier way using `==` and catching the error somehow?

Comment: Are they for sure only one level deep?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Comparing two dictionaries with numpy matrices as values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26420911/comparing-two-dictionaries-with-numpy-matrices-as-values)

Comment: Take a look at the very last answer for the duplicate above.

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
def equal_dictionaries(dic1, dic2):
    for key, value in dic1.items():
        key1 = key
        value1 = value
    for key, value in dic2.items():
        key2 = key
        value2 = value
    if np.array_equal(value1, value2) == False or key1 != key2:
        return False
    else:
        return True
```